# 'IHtmlHelper<IPagedList<MissionCardVM>>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm getting this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  CS1929  'IHtmlHelper<IPagedList>' does not contain a definition for 'PagedListPager' and the best extension method overload 'HtmlHelper.PagedListPager(HtmlHelper, IPagedList, Func<int, string>)' requires a receiver of type 'HtmlHelper'      e:\Study\Project\CI_Platform\MVC\CI-Platform\CI-Platform\Views\Mission\MissionListing.cshtml    271

Due to this error I'm unable to use  `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }));`

I've used all the correct using statements

heres my view

```
@using PagedList.Mvc; 
@using PagedList; 


@model IPagedList<CI_Platform.Entities.Models.ViewModels.MissionCardVM>


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MissionListing";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MissionLayout.cshtml";
}
 <div class="mt-3 justify-content-end" id="disappear-pagination" >
            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example ">
                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }));
            </nav>
        </div>
```

heres my controller

```
public IActionResult MissionListing(string Id, int? page)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("Email") == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                string userid = Id;
                long uid = Convert.ToInt64(userid);
                var user = _cidata.Users.Where(c => c.UserId == uid).FirstOrDefault();

                if (user != null)
                {
                    //returns First Name and Last Name of users
                    ViewBag.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                    ViewBag.LastName = user.LastName;
                   

                }
                int pagesize = 6, pageindex = 1;
                pageindex=page.HasValue ? Convert.ToInt32(page):1;
                var missions = (from m in _cidata.Missions
                                join c in _cidata.Cities on m.CityId equals c.CityId
                                join t in _cidata.MissionThemes on m.ThemeId equals t.MissionThemeId
                                join g in _cidata.GoalMissions on m.MissionId equals g.MissionId into temp
                                from g in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                    //join mr in context.MissionRatings on m.MissionId equals mr.MissionId

                                    //where mr.Rating == (from mr2 in context.MissionRatings
                                    //                    where m.MissionId == mr2.MissionId
                                    //                    select mr2.Rating).Average()

                                select new MissionCardVM
                                {
                                    Title = m.Title,
                                    ShortDescription = m.ShortDescription,
                                    CityName = c.Name,
                                    Theme = t.Title,
                                    OrganizationName = m.OrganizationName,
                                    CountryId = c.CountryId,
                                    MissionType = m.MissionType,
                                    StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(m.StartDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                    EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(m.EndDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                    GoalObjectiveText = g.GoalObjectiveText,
                                    Deadline = m.EndDate.Value.AddHours(-24).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                                    CityId = c.CityId,
                                    //Rating = mr.Rating
                                }).ToList();
                
                IPagedList<MissionCardVM> stu = missions.ToPagedList(pageindex, pagesize);
                
                return View(stu);
            }
            
        }
```

Am I missing out on any using statements ?  All similar questions didn't solve this error.

Comment: whats the origin of `Html.PagedListPager`? i don't remember that thing in the default asp.mvc APIs. is it from a nuget package?

Comment: yes its from a nuget package called PagedList.Mvc

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET 6, you need install nuget package `X.PagedList` and `X.PagedList.Mvc.Core`.

Then import the namespace like below:

```
@using X.PagedList.Mvc.Core; @*import this so we get our HTML Helper*@
@using X.PagedList;
```

Comment: Even tried this but didn't work. So I ended up making custom Pagination. Thanks though !!!